# Looking for a single word for sudden realization of not understanding something

Tags: single-word-requests

You try your best but not comprehend a certain topic for a very long time and eventually you begin to understand it. At this point you would feel sad because you spent so much time on trying to understand this very topic and realize that the topic was actually pretty straight forward to comprehend. What's word for this sad emotion you feel at this very moment? Thanks!

Edit: Thank you for the suggestions. Epiphany is close but it does not represent the sadness of the moment.

Edit2: Clarity.

Edit3: Not catharsis.

Comment: Sounds to me like a new way to tell an optimist from a pessimist: Sad about finally figuring something out=Glass half empty/Happy about it=Half full!

Comment: I've referred to this as an "Aw shit!" moment, similar to an "Aha!" moment but different.

Comment: [*D'oh*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27oh!)  (accompanied by a slap to the forehead.

Comment: @bib "D'oh!" is perfect, i think :)

Comment: *"Snap back to reality, oh there goes gravity"*

Comment: How about *catharsis*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Epiphany](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/epiphany)

> a usually sudden manifestation or perception of the essential nature or meaning of something
>
> an intuitive grasp of reality through something (as an event) usually simple and striking
>
> an illuminating discovery, realization, or disclosureb or a revealing scene or moment

Also, [eyeopener](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/eyeopener)

> an experience or disclosure that gives one a sudden realization or understanding.

Comment: @Drew damn. Why didn't I think of that!

Comment: Neither did Archimedes. Until he did. ;-)